# Calling a Class method in U I layer from other Class Library (3 tier Architecture- from B A L) using JQUERY AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have DAL, BAL and UI interface. I want to call a method from BAL class using Jquery in UI layer. How can I perform this method?

Comment: one word : ajax

Comment: can you help me regarding this?

Comment: I am not able to call it using AJAX. Having problem since morning

Comment: i am not familiar with abbreviated thing like DAL, BAL, better post some code so other can help you

Comment: Data Access Layer(DAL), Business Access Layer (BAL)